# Eval Buffer works on .emacs but loading when emacs starts

Tags: init-file

I know there are some other questions like this on the site, but none of them seem to work.

I am trying to enable relative line numbers with a package, and when I do `M-x eval-buffer`, the mode is enabled, but when I just launch emacs it does not get enabled. I checked and made sure that the location of init.el is the one that emacs is using, and I know that it is at least partially working because I can install packages in it and use them through M-x.

Here is my init.el

```
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (when no-ssl
    (warn "\
Your version of Emacs does not support SSL connections,
which is unsafe because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks.
There are two things you can do about this warning:
1. Install an Emacs version that does support SSL and be safe.
2. Remove this warning from your init file so you won't see it again."))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (linum-relative markdown-mode))))
(setq linum-relative-backend 'display-line-numbers-mode)
(linum-relative-mode)
```

Specifically, `(linum-relative-mode)` doesn't work when launching emacs.

To recreate, set the file above as your init.el / .emacs file and launch emacs. Notice that there are no relative line numbers. Now run `M-x eval-buffer` and see that it adds the buffer just fine. My question is why launching emacs is not evaluating the .emacs file as it should?

Comment: Please don't just post your init file. Narrow it down, removing everything that's just noise - unnecessary to show/reproduce the problem you want to ask about. And please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem. Thx.

Comment: Native relative line numbers are built-in to Emacs 26+, with no additional packages needed.

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linum-relative-mode` will be a buffer-local mode, just like `linum-mode`.  Hence when you evaluate the code, it activates for the current buffer (only).

Regular `linum` provides a global mode `global-linum-mode`, so try `global-linum-relative-mode` ?

or, as lawlist points out, if you are on Emacs 26+ then you should definitely use `global-display-line-numbers-mode` instead (and see <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `display-line-numbers` for options).